# stacking same amount of duplicates + non duplicates of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure how to express this in words, so perhaps a visual is better. Can somebody help me stack in the following way? States are in alphabetical order. So far I have been successful at stacking unique or duplicates, but i cant get to stack the way I really want. Perhaps my best description is to put the max number of states in both columns, but then im not sure how to pair them with the respective cities.

```
Sheet1
State  City
FL     TPA
FL     FTL
MO     STL  
NV     RNO  
TX     HSTN 
TX     AUS


Sheet2
State  City
FL     TPA
FL     FTL
MO     STL      
MO     KSC
MO     HNB
NY     NY
TX     AMR
TX     NWT


Sheet3
State  City
FL     TPA
FL     FTL
MO     STL
MO     KSC
MO     HNB
NV     RNO
NY     NY
TX     HST
TX     AUS
TX     AMR
TX     NWT
```

Comment: I think your question is not clear, could you show us what your desired result would look like?

Comment: Sorry about that. Sheet 3 is the desired column. So I would like to take sheet 1 and sheet 2 and compile them somehow to look like sheet 3.

Comment: *but i cant get to stack the way I really want* - how do you want them stacked? Is the order predefined? Because besides sorting alphabetically by state? I don't see how city is sorted in a meaningful way. If you just need the output in any city order, you can copy and paste both lists to a sheet3 and then use remove duplicates feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one needs heavy use of `Dictionary`. Basically you need one for the states, and for each state its own dictionary of cities. Try this code, it produces the exact same output of `Sheet3` in your example:

```
Sub MergeStatesAndCities()
  Dim r As Range, dicStates As Object, sh As Worksheet
  Set dicStates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each r In sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A999999").End(xlUp))
      'set a dictionary of cities for each state!
      If Not dicStates.Exists(r.Text) Then Set dicStates(r.Text) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
      dicStates(r.Text)(r.Offset(, 1).Text) = 0 ' add key for the city if not already there
    Next
  Next

  ' Now bring the values into new sheet
  Set sh = Sheets.Add
  sh.name = "AllStatesAndCities"
  sh.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("State", "City")
  Dim state
  For Each state In dicStates.keys
    With sh.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(dicStates(state).Count)
      .Value = state
      .Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dicStates(state).keys)
    End With
  Next

  ' Now Sort the result by states
  sh.UsedRange.Columns("A:B").Sort key1:=sh.Range("A2"), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compiled error: User-defined type not defined. Then it highlights ", dicStates As Scripting.dictionary"

Comment: @Jahir use the last version of my code, it uses late binding for the `Dictionary`, no need to set any reference.

Comment: thank you very much. This works as I was hoping. OMG to think I spent 2 days trying to do this by formulas and was never able to account for the whole thing. Thanks a lot, I shall learn about dictionaries from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you can just copy both sheets, Remove Duplicates, and Sort:

```
Sheet1.Cells.Copy Sheet3.Cells
Sheet2.UsedRange.Copy Sheet3.Cells.End(xlDown)(2)
Sheet3.Cells.RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2)
Sheet3.Cells.Sort Sheet3.Columns(1), , Sheet3.Columns(2), , , , , xlYes
```